# How to remove number type inside text widget on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**i have list text widget :**

`<Widget>((e)=> Text(e)).toList().`

with value of **e** is : `123988montain`

then how to remove **number** on list Text.
i want that **value** on **List Text** show without **number**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to remove the numbers from the e variable before passing it to the Text widget :

```
List<Widget> textWidgets = ["123988montain"].map((e) {
  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r'[\d]+');
  e = e.replaceAll(exp, '');
  return Text(e);
}).toList();
```

You can also use *replaceFirst* instead of *replaceAll* function to remove only the first matched numbers

Comment: actually it is for `<Widget>((e)=> Text(e).toList()`. value of `e` is `123988montain` then how to remove number on list Text

Comment: And I have edited the answer accordingly @Alammerdeka